# Helping making multiple text fields visible or invisible

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm taking an intro into Android Studio class and for homework we had to build a Geometric Shapes App. The principle is similar to what we've done in a previous assignment, expect in this assignment we have multiple shapes and fields. To make things a bit more challenging our teacher threw in a curve and he said he wanted us to display the appropriate fields per shape. So a

circle would display area and circumference
sphere would display volume and surface area

However, the shapes wouldn't display information that wasn't relevant to each shape. We were given two hints

1.) b.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //to make button disappear
2.) Use Google to solve any additional items

**My current problem is**: when the user selects a shape such as a circle it asks them to enter everything:

- radius
- height
- length

Then when they click "find volume" my output displays everything

- area
- circumference
- volume
- surface area
- etc ....

I have one button setup

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFindVolume);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //find out type of shape selected by the user
            Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerShapes);
            shapeType = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

            //Extract the radius from the radius field
            EditText radiusText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRadius);
            radius = Double.parseDouble(radiusText.getText().toString());

            //Extract the height from the height field
            EditText heightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHeight);
            height = Double.parseDouble(heightText.getText().toString());

            //Extract the length from the length field
            EditText lengthText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLength);
            length = Double.parseDouble(lengthText.getText().toString());
```

Along with IF statements to calculate the shapes volume

```
if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")) {

                    //compute area and circumference of the circle
                    area = (PI * radius * radius);
                    circumference = (2 * PI) * (radius);

                    //pack circle area and circumference into intent
                    intent.putExtra("computedArea", area);
                    intent.putExtra("competedCircumference", circumference);

                    //start the target activity - VolumeDisplay
                    startActivity(intent);

            } else if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Cylinder")) {

                //compute volume of the cylinder
                volume = PI * radius * radius * height;

                //pack cylinder volume into intent for the volume display activity
                intent.putExtra("computedVolume", volume);

                //start the target activity - VolumeDisplay
                startActivity(intent);
```

My question is how do I use set.visibility and what suggestions do you guys have towards how I should implement them at the beginning of my program when a user selects a shape and at the end when information is displayed.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend you to make something like this:

In you xml layout hide all the items except the spinner.

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

Then you add a onItemSelectedlistener to your spinner, something like this:

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

    shapeType =  parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")){
    // your code for set visibility to edittext here.
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

}
});
```

Then inside the onItemSelectedListener you should setVisivility(View.VISIBLE) or View.GONE depending what field you should show for each shape, for example:

if the spinner item selected is a circle:

```
 radiusText.setVisivility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Also, if you want to make a good homework you can add to the editText the following listener to show/hide or enable/disable the submit button if the edittext have some text or not.

```
radiusText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.lenght > 0) {
        b.setVisivilty(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        b.setVisivilty(View.GONE);
    }
}
});

  b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")){
                area = (PI * radius * radius);
                circumference = (2 * PI) * (radius);

                //pack circle area and circumference into intent
                intent.putExtra("computedArea", area);
                intent.putExtra("competedCircumference", circumference);
          }else if(shapeType ..) {// THE OTHER ITEMS

          }

          startActivity(intent);
    });
```

Comment: So for the 'radiusText' would I have if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")) {
                        //compute area and circumference of the circle
                        area = (PI * radius * radius);
                        circumference = (2 * PI) * (radius);
                        //pack cone area and circumference into intent for the volume display activity
                        intent.putExtra("computedArea", area);
                        intent.putExtra("competedCircumference" in the set on item selected?

Answer (score 0):

Create a RadioGroup instead of shape Buttons with TextFields Directly under radioGroup 
**Add this in you  xml above EditText's**

```
 <RadioGroup   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:id="@+id/shapes"    
            android:background="#abf234"    
            android:checkedButton="@+id/circle" >

            <RadioButton    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/cylinder"
                android:text="@string/Cylinder" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/sphere"    
                android:text="@string/Sphere" />   

            <RadioButton    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:id="@+id/circle"   
                android:text="@string/Circle" />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Declare all necessary fields in `onCreate()` and make them visible/invisible based on shape,so that user can enter only the value required

```
     EditText radiusText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRadius);
     EditText heightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHeight);
     EditText lengthText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLength);     
     RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRadioGroup);

        //initailly check item is circle so display fields for cycle
         lengthText.setVisible(View.GONE);
         radiusText.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
         heightText.setVisible(View.GONE);
          radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // find which radio button is selected
                    if(checkedId == R.id.circle) {
                         //make circle fields visible and others invisible 
                    } else if(checkedId == R.id.cylinder) {
                        //make cylinder fields visible and others invisible
                    } else {
                         //make sphere fields visible and others invisible
                    }
                }            
            });

//this will be common submit button instead of shapes buttons
        submitbtn.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick()
        {
         int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
          View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
         int checkedid= radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
         if(checkedid==0)
         {
          //sphere calculations
           }
          else if(checkedid==1)
          {
          //cylinder calculations
          }
         else{
         //circle calculations 
          }
        } 
        });
```